# Obtener bisnieto de un div

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo obtener el bisnieto de un `div`? Ojo **sin librerías, solo JavaScript puro**. En este caso no solo se trata del bisnieto, pero en realidad quiero ubicar cualquier hijo, nieto o bisnieto.

En el siguiente código, ¿es recomendable usar `[0]`? Si cambio el elemento de posición, el *tag* ya no funcionaría. Me refiero que el índice indica a una posición y si se adiciona o elimina un *tag* se obtendrán diferentes elementos.

```js
var x = document.getElementById("uno");
var y = x.children[0];
console.log(x, y);
```

```html
<div id="uno">
  <div id="cuatro">
    otro
  </div>
  <div id="dos">
    <div id="tres">
      hola
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **bis**nieto? o nieto? y sólo el primero del primero? qué si hay más?

Comment: @Mariano en realidad quiero ubicar cualquier hijo, nieto o bisnieto

Comment: Creo que deberías aclarar eso **en la pregunta**, especificando si es uno en específico, o si la idea es obtener **todos**... Recordá que cuanto más específicas sean tus preguntas, cuanto mejor puedas expresar el problema, mejores respuestas vas a obtener.

Comment: @Mariano mi otra duda es que no creo que es recomendable usar posiciones [0]..

Comment: "*si cambio el de posicion el tag ya no funcionaria*" <-- creo que sería bueno ver un ejemplo de qué te estás refiriendo con "cambio" (podría ser cambiando la estructura de muchas formas posibles, mejor ver un ejemplo)

Answer (score 4):

Recomiendo extender el prototipo de `Node`, ya que todo `HTMLElement` hereda el prototipado de `Node`, esto se recomienda cuando el uso de la funcion es intenso, se puede ver como una sintáxis más azucarada o bien una extención a la WebAPI

```js
;(function()
{
"use strict"
/**
 * Obtiene el i-ésimo hijo de un Nodo
 * nodo.getChildDepth(i)
 */
Node.prototype.getChildDepth = function(depth) 
{
 var depth = depth && depth > 0 ? depth : 1
 var child = this.children[0] // fix text nodes

 for (let i = 0; child != undefined && (i < depth - 1) ; i++) 
   {
    child = child.children[0]
   }

 return child
}
var body = document.body;
console.log(body.getChildDepth(1)) // return div#uno
console.log(body.getChildDepth(2))// return div#dos
console.log(body.getChildDepth(3)) // return div#tres
console.log(body.getChildDepth(4)) // return undefined
}())
```

```html
<div id="uno">
  <div id="dos">
    <div id="tres">
      hola
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto solo encontraría un único descendiente de nivel n y tan solo del primer elemento, ¿no?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro correcto, cuando el usuario abrió la pregunta, no especificó que quería obtener todos los hijos a un mismo nivel.

Comment: Ah! Acabo de ver el historial de revisiones. Efectivamente en su primera versión el código era diferente

Answer (score 4):

Sé que este método puede parecer un poco loco, pero puedes hacer uso del selector de descendiente directo `>`  junto al selector universal `*`, para seleccionar todos los descendientes de nivel N.

El selector universal es el menos eficiente y más lento, pero en los navegadores modernos (y limitando su ámbito de acción a una parte de la página en concreto) su impacto en el rendimiento de la página no debería ser importante. Si sólo quieres trabajar con `div`, podrías reemplazar el `*` de abajo por `div` y el resultado sería más eficiente.

A partir de eso, puedes hacer una función que cree un selector de N niveles (por ejemplo, los hijos serían `#padre > *`, los nietos serían `#padre > * > *`, los bisnietos serían `#padre > * > * > *`, y así sucesivamente). Por cada nivel debería haber un `> *`.

Entonces tendríamos esta función que tomaría como parámetros el selector del elemento del que queremos obtener sus descendientes, y un número especificando el nivel del descendiente:

```
function getDescendientesDeNivel(selector, nivel) {
  // si no es un nivel válido, devolvemos false
  if (!nivel || nivel < 1) { return false; }
  // creamos un selector con el selector del elemento raíz y n veces  "> *"
  var selector = selector + Array(nivel + 1).join(" > *");
  // devolvemos los elementos seleccionados
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Y aquí dejo una demo:

```js
function getDescendientesDeNivel(selector, nivel) {
  if (!nivel || nivel < 1) { return false; }
  var selector = selector + Array(nivel + 1).join(" > *");
  return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

var hijos = getDescendientesDeNivel("#padre", 1);
var nietos = getDescendientesDeNivel("#padre", 2);
var bisnietos = getDescendientesDeNivel("#padre", 3);
var tataranietos = getDescendientesDeNivel("#padre", 4);

console.log(bisnietos);
```

```html
<div id="padre">
  <div id="hijo-1">
    <div id="nieto-1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo-2">
    <div id="nieto-2">
      <div id="bisnieto-1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nieto-3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo-3">
    <div id="nieto-4">
    </div>
    <div id="nieto-5">
      <div id="bisnieto-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Esta función se puede utilizar para extender el prototipo de `Node` (como sugiere [Eduen en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83542/250)), lo cual se podría hacer usando `:scope` para especificar que se empieza a buscar desde el elemento activo:

```
Node.prototype.getDescendientesDeNivel = function(nivel) {
  if (!nivel || nivel < 1) { return false; }
  var selector = ":scope " + Array(nivel + 1).join(" > *");
  return this.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
```

Que puedes ver funcionando aquí:

```js
Node.prototype.getDescendientesDeNivel = function(nivel) {
  if (!nivel || nivel < 1) { return false; }
  var selector = ":scope " + Array(nivel + 1).join(" > *");
  return this.querySelectorAll(selector);
}

var padre = document.getElementById("padre");
var hijos = padre.getDescendientesDeNivel(1);
var nietos = padre.getDescendientesDeNivel(2);
var bisnietos = padre.getDescendientesDeNivel(3);
var tataranietos = padre.getDescendientesDeNivel(4);

console.log(bisnietos);
```

```html
<div id="padre">
  <div id="hijo-1">
    <div id="nieto-1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo-2">
    <div id="nieto-2">
      <div id="bisnieto-1">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nieto-3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="hijo-3">
    <div id="nieto-4">
    </div>
    <div id="nieto-5">
      <div id="bisnieto-2">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Una posibilidad seria que, luego de seleccionar el div padre hicieras un `getElementsByTagName('div')` para obtener todos los div que están aninados.

Luego como deseas el ultimo con hacer length - 1 obtienes el que buscas.

```js
var x=document.getElementById("uno").getElementsByTagName("div");
console.log(x[x.length - 1]);
```

```html
<div id="uno">
  <div id="dos">
    <div id="tres">
      hola
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

La segunda opción es como lo estabas haciendo pero te faltó  `x.children[0].children` ya que children devuelve un array de hijos, por ende debes usar el `[0]` para especificar en que hijo vas a buscar (En este caso como solo hay 1, se coloca 0) y luego de esto, decir que te devuelva sus hijos.

```js
var x=document.getElementById("uno");
var y=x.children[0].children;
console.log(y);
```

```html
<div id="uno">
  <div id="dos">
    <div id="tres">
      hola
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con tu propio codigo proporcionado puede ser posible. Solo tendiramos que acceder a los children del segundo elemento:

```js
var x=document.getElementById("uno");
 var y=x.children;
 var bisnieto = y[0].children[0];
 console.log(x);
 console.log(bisnieto)
```

```html
<div id="uno">
  <div id="dos">
    <div id="tres">
      hola
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sería preferible que el ejemplo ejecutable lo pongas en el cuerpo de tu respuesta. Mientras estás editando, click en el botón `< >`.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no es necesario usar librerías para esto, ya que javascript provee de una herramienta de escaneo del DOM muy poderosa que se basa en la búsqueda a partir de selectores CSS

> **«*querySelectorAll*»** devuelve una lista de los elementos dentro del
>   documento, ... es compatible con Chrome 1+, Firefox (Gecko) 3.5+,
>   Internet Explorer 8+, Opera 10+  y Safari (WebKit) 3.2+

para mas mas información puedes consultar en: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Una forma de implementarlo en tu problema seria algo así:

```js
var descendencia = document.querySelectorAll("#uno div"); //Lista a cualquier div descendiente
var i = descendencia.length;                              //Cuentas las coincidencias
while (i--) {                                             
  console.log(descendencia.item(i));                      
}
```

```html
<div id="uno">
  <div id="cuatro">otro</div>
  <div id="dos">
    <div id="tres">hola</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: me convences aunque no del todo tu respuesta, hay alguna forma de no usar un iterador? while?

Comment: `descendencia` es en el ejemplo una lista y puedes acceder a sus ítems a través del método  `item`, así que si sabes exactamente cuantos descendientes tienes puedes hallarlos así por ejemplo: `descendencia.item(0)` <-- aquí obtendrías al primer nodo encontrado, pero si tienes una cantidad indefinida de descendientes lo mejor es usar cualquier ciclo.